# I need help understanding the bind function in C socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, pointers

I'm trying to really understand sockets, so I am learning it in C. This is the server code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

int main() {

    char server_message[255] = "You have reached the server!";

    //create server socket
    int server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    //define server addr
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    //Bind socket to IP and Port
    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    listen(server_socket, 5);

    int client_socket;
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);

    //send message
    send(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0);

    //close socket
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

In the bind function, this part is needed to specify the address

```
(struct sockaddr*) &server_address
```

I read the man page, and it does say it has to be this way, the code also runs, but I don't understand this syntax. What is happening in this part of the code. I know * is used to declare pointers, and & refers to the memory address of the variable. I just can't put it all together.

Comment: The function accepts a `struct sockaddr *`, but that's just a generic pointer for the underlying structures, which are IP-version specific. You have to cast the pointer of the type you actually use to the type that the function accepts.

Comment: The `(struct sockaddr*)` part is a *cast*, or type conversion, operator. It converts a value of one type (a pointer in this case) to a value of another type (a different type of pointer in this case).

Comment: So basically, this is making a sockaddr pointer and assigning the memory address of server_address to it?